# what is the way to jump to method signature in netbeans php?

Tags: php, netbeans, editor

The problem is that I would like to get a little comfortable while I am coding PHP in Netbeans.
When edit cursor is in the middle of the source of long metod
I would like to press a **key shortcut** to jump to the beginning of that method.

Eg:

```
public function doStuff($arg1,$arg2) <--- I want to jump here...
{
$a = $b;
$b = $c;
$c = $d;
$d = $e; <--- cursor is here
.....
}
```

Comment: is the "Navigator" not enough? Or do you not wish to move mouse while typing?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to move my hand to mouse while typing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works fine for me : `Ctrl+7` + `return`

Answer (score 0):

The best solution: don't write functions which are longer than one screen (and that's already pretty damn long).

Long functions with many local variables are very bad for maintainability: they're hard to understand and will contain disproportionally more bugs.

Instead, break them up into smaller functions that do only one thing and have a name that describes exactly what they do.

Comment: I have lots of functions that are longer than a screen, is it not more important to keep related function within that function instead of passing it out to smaller functions, in terms of readability and updating

Comment: @gunnx: pretty much everyone with experience agrees that it's not, and there are entire books written about good coding practices that all agree on this. The point is that functions should provide an abstraction: the name should explain what it does, so in the "outer" function that calls multiple smaller ones, you just see their names and know what they do, so you can think at a higher level of abstraction. Additionally, smaller functions are much more reusable, preventing duplication of functionality.

Comment: Yes I agree that smaller functions are reusable. I just hadn't heard anyone describe that functions should be less than a screen height

Comment: @gunnx: It's actually quite common to see people promote a much smaller average length to aim for. The widely acclaimed "Clean Code" book says "Functions should hardly ever be 20 lines long." Take a look at the quotes and discussion here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/133404/

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to have a look over my code and see how much of it fits within these rules.